# Pass Sequence as Argument in Place of Multiple Arguments

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

How can I/should I pass a **single** sequence as an argument to a function which expects **multiple** arguments? Specifically, I'm trying to use [cartesian-product](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.combinatorics/cartesian-product) and pass it a sequence (see below); however, when I do so the result is not the desired one. If I can't pass a single sequence as the argument, how can I/should I break up the sequence into multiple arguments? Thanks.

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.combinatorics :only (cartesian-product)])
(cartesian-product (["a" "b" "c"] [1 2 3]))
```

Results in:

```
((["a" "b"]) ([1 2]))
```

Desired result

```
(("a" 1) ("a" 2) ("b" 1) ("b" 2))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `apply` function builds a function call from a function and a sequence containing the arguments to the function.

```
(apply cartesian-product  '(["a" "b" "c"] [1 2 3]))
(("a" 1) ("a" 2) ("a" 3) ("b" 1) ("b" 2) ("b" 3) ("c" 1) ("c" 2) ("c" 3))
```

as another example:

```
(apply + (range 10))
```

evaluates `(range 10)` into a sequence `(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)` and then builds this function call

```
(+ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

---

and back by popular demand:

**for**tunatly the for function does this nicely.

```
(for [x ["a" "b"] y [1 2]] [x y])
(["a" 1] ["a" 2] ["b" 1] ["b" 2])
```

Comment: sorry for the pun... I will edit to add a real answer also in a moment

Comment: Note that you should use vectors in preference to quoted lists since the latter would prevent evaluation of the elements.

Comment: @Ari, if you click on the text after "edited" you can see old revisions. I'm not sure why you took the for(tunate) example out; seems an appropriate and simple solution to me. I suppose it needs to be used in combination with destructing or equivalent to be a full solution, but it's still informative.

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is one way as Arthur shows.

Another possibility to consider is [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5Bbindings%2A%20%5D%20exprs%2A%29). Specifically nested vector binding:

`user=> (let [[v1 v2] '([:a :b] [1 2])]
         (cartesian-product v1 v2))`

Comment: Thanks for sharing an alternative solution; I appreciate it. I selected Arthur's suggestion, because the sequence argument, in my problem, is of variable size.